# Where to place the gruntfile in a Spring Web application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, gruntjs

I'm not sure where is the best is to place my Grunt file in my spring web application. Should it be placed at the root of the web application like so:

```
my-app/gruntfile.js
```

Or should I place it at the root of resource directory like so:

```
my-app/src/main/webapp/static
```

Both will work. Just wondering what's the best practice here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grunt file is usually not part of the deployable. So it should not be src/main/webapp folder.I usually place my gulp file (pretty mutch the same thing) in the project root folder.

If you plan do minify or compile with grunt. You usually need a folder for the original files and one for the compiled files. My experience is that it is a bad idea to compile the files directly into the src/main/webapp folder since IDE's track them and reindex them every time. So I integrated gulp  into the gradle lifecycle and copy all files into the webapp folder when I create the deployable.

Comment: the grunt file not being part of the deploy is very true. Just didn't think of that as i've been running the spring boot application right off my IDE. I will place the build tools at the project root as prescribed. any other thing i need can be configured. Thanks a lot. I like how @selvinsource placed them in a client folder though, kinda makes it cleaner somewhat

Answer (score 1):

I think a good project structure for spring and a client side library like AngularJS is:

```
 my-app/src/
    * main
        * client: gruntfile.js, bower.json, js and html files
        * java: spring java code
        * resources: application.properties, static folder (for compiled client)
```

I would also take a look at some generators such as
http://yeoman.io/ or http://jhipster.github.io/
which create new projects with best practices and tools.